# How to allow custom program on 80 port via selinux

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I have custom webserver that i want to run on 80 port. The problem is its being blocked by selinux. So from localhost I can browse the site, but from outer world its not accessible.

I run the program this way,

```
   /opt/project1/run.py -p 80.
```

Comment: Are you running this service as root?

Comment: Yes, But later I'll run it under a user. May be `sudo -u usename /opt/project1/run.py -p 80` will do it?

Comment: Only root can bind to "privileged ports" on UNIX systems, that is ports under 1024.  A typical practice is to handle incoming connections as root, then fork to a handler process running as a non-privileged user.

Comment: @KyleSmith I think you didn't get the point of my question. I am not saying I can not bind it. I can bind. Problem is its only accessible from local host but not from outer world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain it's selinux that blocks this from working, and not either:

- The software firewall, `iptables`.  Take a look at the output of `iptables -nvL` to see what rules are applied.
- The way the server listens for incoming connections.  (This is typically handled by binding to a specific address.  For example, if you are binding to listen on `127.0.0.1:80`, you cannot accept connections from anywhere except localhost.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. It was indeed firewall issue. BTW, I bind it to 0.0.0.0:80. I can see that by netstat